# Catch user group in login flow and remove access to frontend if belongs to certain group

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a application with frontend and backend sides. Both share the same FOSUserBundle users table. The logic behind the application I'm working on doesn't allow "admin" (`ROLE_ADMIN` or group `ADMIN`) to be logged in at frontend so I need to catch on login flow whether the user belongs to group `ADMIN` or has `ROLE_SUPERADMIN` or `ROLE_ADMIN` credentials. I think this could be done in someway on the [Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) flow from Symfony2 itself, but how? What I need to do to catch that and if user belongs redirect to login form (from FOSUserBundle) or allow it to get into the frontend? Any help? Some code? Examples?

**`security.yml` file content:**

Regarding user answer this is how my `security.yml` file is configured:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

access_control:
    # Anonymous area
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/registro, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/cedula, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/rif, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/correo, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/usuario, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/razon_social, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/registro_mercantil, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/padre, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/correo_alternativo, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/paises, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/estados, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/ciudades, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/municipios, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/parroquias, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/empresas, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Secured area
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But users with `ROLE_ADMIN` can still login in frontend (`/`) and them shouldn't right? What's wrong then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know the role hierarchy in your security.yml file.

You don't need to extend default functionality on fosuserbundle or symfony security to achieve that.

For example:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE USER
    ROLE_CONTENT_MANAGER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_CONTENT_MANAGER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

So, super admin can go anywhere all other grups allowed. Admin, has the rights of content manager. Content manager has the rights of user.

Check your access control in your security.yml file.

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/private_directory$, roles: MUST_BE_RIGHT_TO_SEE_HERE }
```

So, the role MUST_BE_RIGHT_TO_SEE_HERE can only see the private_directory. Any other roles can not.

Comment: Is not working for me, can you take a look at the configuration I leave on main post?

Comment: I think IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN roles ares constants. User automatically has user rights when the role is admin. I don't know bro...